# Ruby refactoring of a method

Tags: ruby, refactoring, enumerable

Would love to refactor this into just one line:

```
def sum_something
  sum = 0
  self.each { |a| sum += a }
  return sum
end
```

There must be a way to define 'sum' within the block and I could drop the 'return'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def sum_something
  inject(0, :+)
end
```

Comment: Actually good Ruby style dictates that you use `reduce(:+)` (an alias for `inject`) in such scenarios (an mentioned in TRPL).

Comment: Whether or not TRPL is any kind of authority on the subject of which alias to pick is arguable, but feel free to quote the respective part of the book, because I have no intentions of reading it.

Comment: If the array is empty, this will return nil, rather than 0. `inject(:+, 0)` would be an exact match.

Comment: @Andrew: yup, folding needs the identity element of the operation being performed (addition: 0). The arguments are the other way around, though.